# Not able to match ChromeDriver version with chrome version

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, python, sdet

So at my current job I’m at a pinch, we can’t just download executable jars and use them. We have to request to download whatever we want . So the problem is , our chrome gets auto updated where as we need to ask for permission to download chromeDriver(all drivers in general). This is a lengthy process and is not feasible . By the time they approve it, a new version of chrome is usually out . So It’s very difficult to get the automation testing started , our chrome and chrome driver versions are always different . I was planning to use Java with selenium but at this point , this is blocking it from happening .

Is there any alternative to this ? I tried using webdriverManager but that dependency is not in our dependency library so that’s not a option aswell. Our system blocks the required files to download when trying to implement that dependency.

At this point , I’m even willing to use python if there is a way to ignore the webdriver executable jar issue . Is there any kind of framework I can use that dosent require a instance of webdriver .

Comment: What is analyzed in this approval process? What impedes you from removing the need for this approval? One can download the chromedriver jars using HTTPS, so it's secure.

Comment: Yeah how they have it set up. We need to request for them to add it in our let’s say “requester application “. It takes awhile to be added there and by that time unfortunately chrome usually gets updated again

Answer (score 0):

Working solution :

- I face this issue and instead of trying solution via automation, Trick work for me perfectly
- I have chosen solution by simply stopping auto update works

How to do it?

- **Solution 1** : You can follow the below steps:

[image]

- **Solution 2** :

  - Go to path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\
  - Find the folder "update"
  - Rename from Update.bak [Example - Update.bak to Update1.bak]
  - As file with name Update won't be available and could not auto update any more.

Enjoy!

Comment: If I could stop the auto update I would have done that long ago. It’s controlled by the organization

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use Docker or Podman, you might consider using [docker-selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium).  These container images come prepackaged with Chrome, Chromedriver, and Selenium, and you can control how often you get updates.

```
docker run --rm -it -p 4444:4444 -p 7900:7900 --shm-size 3g selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
```

The above, for instance, would start a Google Chrome container, and you can view it at localhost:7900 in your browser. However, this depends on your IT department allowing you to pull docker container images.

Comment: Can’t use docker :(. Is there any way I can point the driver to the chrome I have downloaded in my machine ? I think playwright allows that

Comment: Playwright and WebdriverIO can both use the DevTools protocol.  This allows your tests to talk directly to the browser and eliminates the need for a WebDriver.  That could be your solution.